# change browser for sencha touch 2

Tags: browser, sencha-touch-2, webgl

We are developing an app with **Sencha Touch 2** and **PhoneGap 2.0**. We also want to use **WebGL**.

But neither the android browser nor safari mobile supports it.

However **Opera Mobile 12** supports **WebGL**. Is it possible to start the sencha app with **Opera Mobile**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, PhoneGap overrides the capability of Native Android browser. We cannot use the Opera Mobile browser features for developing the PhoneGap Applications.

Secondly, Sencha Touch is not supported by Opera Mobile. It runs only on WebKit browsers. I am not sure about Mobile chrome. But any other browser except android default browser will not able to run all features of sencha.

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try RhoElements v1 browser.  It also only supports WebKit as far as I know.

https://docs.symbol.com/ReleaseNotes/RE_0100001000_ReleaseNotes.html

http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2012/01/04/rhodes-3-3-x-supports-motorola-rhoelements-and-android-et1/